# How to model my data in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js

Two questions:

1) I am using angular-js and I am looking for a way to model my data.
I have experience with the idea of a Model in backbone.
Is this a factory in angular? Is it an ok "best practice" to have a LOT of factories (one for each type of model), basically mimicking "class" with "factory"?

The factory represents my model with some "helper" functions (like a model on Backbone) or my factory represents a list of members (like a collection on backbone)?

2) For example, Let's say I want to create objects to map to REST resources and I have an "member" resource that I get by GET-ing: /members/123. This returns a json object with various fields. Something like:

{id: 123, name: 'angularjs', date_created: 1235845}

Now, I want some kind of representation in my AngularJS app of this "member" object. This representation is more than just a mapping of the fields - I want to add "helper" functions, for example a function that converts the date_create field into something human-readable.

How to represent this? using factory + $resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is good example how tot use factory in your case.

**Factory**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Member', function($http) {
  // Member is a class which we can use for retrieving and 
  // updating data on the server
  var Member = function(data) {
    angular.extend(this, data);
  }

  // a static method to retrieve Member by id
  Member.get = function(id) {
    return $http.get('/Member/' + id).
      then(function(response) {
      return new Member(response.data);
    });
  };

  // an instance method to create a new Member
  Member.prototype.create = function() {
    var member= this;
    return $http.post('/Member/', member).then(function(response) {
      book.id = response.data.id;
      return member;
    });
  }

  return Member;
});
```

Then in controller you can write something like:

**Controller**

```
var controller = function(Member) {

  var memeber= new Member();
  memeber.name = 'Fox';
  memeber.create();

  // to retrieve a memeber
  var memeberPromise = Memeber.get(123);
  memeberPromise.then(function(b) {
    memeber = b;
  });
};
```

Here I used `id` only but you understand the flow

Hope it will help you to sort things out